# rsync extremely slow with exported/mounted folder, much faster with ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync, nfs

I have an NAS device set up as a backup for all my home systems, and currently it is set up to use ssh with code adapted from [here](https://netcodger.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/rsync-backup-to-my-book-live/).  A shorted version of my code is:

```
NAS=192.168.1.143                         #IP address or resolvable hostname of NAS
SrcDirs="/Data"
DestDir=/nfs/Public/backup   #Backup destination on NAS
Date=`date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S"`

nice rsync -azv \
--link-dest=$DestDir/current \
--delete \
--delete-excluded \
--exclude=Temp \
$SrcDirs root@$NAS:$DestDir/backup-$Date
```

This has worked great for a long time, but ssh on the NAS is really old and I'm having issues getting it to work with newer systems.  To get around the ssh problem, I exported the backup folder on the NAS and mounted it on the guest systems:

from /etc/exports on the NAS:

```
/nfs/Public *(rw,all_squash,sync,anonuid=500,anongid=1000)
```

from /etc/fstab on the main system:

```
192.168.1.143:/nfs                /nfs                    nfs     defaults        0 0
```

Then, I point the backup script above to the mounted folder instead of going through ssh.  Simple enough, but now rsync is ridiculously slow.  Is there something about the way that I have the export and mount set up that would cause rsync to slow to a crawl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues that could be affecting the speed.

1. Network vs local copies with `rsync`

   `rsync` works best when it's being used across a network connection. Your old scheme (`rsync -az /src/path remote:/dst/path`) allowed `rsync` to transfer only parts of files that had changed (skipping entirely those that had the same file size and last-modified date). As far as `rsync` is concerned, your new scheme has no network (`rsync -a /src/path /dst/path`) so it has to choose between skipping a file because it seems to be unchanged and transferring it in its entirely. What's more, compression is ignored when copying between "local" paths so even files that are newly created and need to be transferred *in toto* would take longer to copy.

   If your NAS has a really slow processor, you might get better throughput omitting the `-z` (compression) flag from `rsync`.
2. Are hard-links still working as expected

   You have `rsync` optimised to try and hard-link unchanged files into the directory tree. It would be worth counting the number of hard-linked files vs the number of "unique" files to ensure that `rsync` is doing what you expect

   ```
   # On the NAS
   find /dst/path -type f | wc -l              # Total number of files backed up
   find /dst/path -type f -links +1 | wc -l    # Should be a significant percentage of total
   ```

   If you find that the `find … -links +1` variant is not the majority of your total files then either you really have modified so much that inevitably `rsync` is going to take a long time, or the tool cannot find files in your `/dst/current` to hard-link.
3. NFS protocol tweaks

   I haven't used NFS for a while, but things to look out for are the I/O block size and file locking. Early NFS implementations defaulted to what is now a ridiculously low block-size, due to the slow LAN speeds available at the time. Check it either auto-tunes or that it's been increased significantly. You may get a useful speed improvement by disabling file locking.

If your backup is copying across a trusted LAN you could look to see if your NAS has an `rsync` daemon (`rsyncd`) that you can enable. This will give all the benefits of `rsync` running in client-server mode but without the encryption (and compatibility issues you mentioned) afforded by `ssh`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response!  This is extremely helpful.  What I realilzed is that rsync is actually working as expected to back up the remote system, but I have some additional commands that operate through SSH in my backup script.  These SSH-dependent steps are getting stuck with the increased security protocols on the client relative to the server.   I'll do some additional tests on the mounted drive as per your suggestions.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just checked a few things regarding your suggestions.  For #2, above, yes, hard links are working as expected with 99.9% linkes (out of 21,000+ files).  Regarding the rsyncd, I do see that the rsync daemon is running on the NAS (ps x | grep rsync gives back the rsync process running), but it still seems to require SSH.  I'll have to look into alternative authentication - any suggestions?

Comment: You should be looking for `rsyncd` (`ps -ef | grep [r]syncd`). I would expect you to need to configure it. You then talk to it from the client in almost exactly the same way as with `ssh` except that you use a double colon rather then a single one. On the client try `rsync -av 192.168.1.143::` to list any available shares

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  I'll take a look at the daemon option more thoroughly.  Thank you again for your help!